# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, broadcast, runtimeexception

I have a problem with a simple project, a broadcast that sends a message and the receiver have a toast . It works, but when I add a class of Xposed gives me the following error.

```js
Process: com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar, PID: 5120
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar.Temar: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar.Temar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2590)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar.Temar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2585)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar.Temar
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
            ... 13 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar.Temar
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.temar" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".Temar"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.enviar">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="30" />

    </application>

</manifest>

            
            
            
public class Temar extends BroadcastReceiver implements IXposedHookInitPackageResources {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    @Override
    public void handleInitPackageResources(InitPackageResourcesParam resparam) throws Throwable {}
  }
            
            
 //SendBroadcast

public void enviarcolor(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.nul00.de.ro.android.xposed.enviar");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    i.putExtra("colores", "#33b2e2");
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

the broadcast works. but just when implent the "implements IXposedHookInitPackageResources " the program does FC.
the construction of the module is good because I have already verified.

I saw that you can solve entering the project properties in eclipse, but as I developed Android studio I have no idea how to do it , if anyone knows the solution or you can guide me on how to access the PROPERTIES to add the libraries , I'll be thankful

Comment: "Clean" and "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Then run your code.

Comment: I already did and did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your package name where you defined is different from package in your manifest. So copy the main activity in proper package , clean project and run app.
Mention activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="package.Tanver"
        > </activity>
```